# Determine if file is empty (SSIS)

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

I am trying to develop a package in SSIS 2005 and part of my process is to check if a file on the network is empty or not. If it is not empty, I need to pass a status of successful, otherwise, I need to pass a status of unsuccessful. I think I need a script task, but am not sure how to go about it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a Script task will do the job here.  Add a using System.IO statement to the top of the script, then something along the lines of the following in the Main method will check the contents of the file.

```
        public void Main()
    {
        String FilePath = Dts.Variables["User::FilePath"].Value.ToString();

        String strContents;
        StreamReader sReader;
        sReader = File.OpenText(FilePath);
        strContents = sReader.ReadToEnd();
        sReader.Close();
        if (strContents.Length==0)
            MessageBox.Show("Empty file");

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

Edit: VB.Net version for 2005...

```
    Public Sub Main()

    Dim FilePath As String = Dts.Variables("User::FilePath").Value.ToString()
    Dim strContents As String
    Dim sReader As StreamReader

    sReader = File.OpenText(FilePath)
    strContents = sReader.ReadToEnd()
    sReader.Close()
    If strContents.Length = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Empty file")
    End If

    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
End Sub
```

Comment: Writing a script seems overly complex, compared to the solution below of using a "Row Count" item.

Comment: Where should I add the script? A picture diagram would be very helpful for this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 12):

Create a connection to the flat file in the Connection Managers panel.
Under the Control flow tab, add a Data Flow Task.
[image]

Double click the Data flow task and add a Flat File Source and Row Count item.
[image]

In the Row Count properties, create a RowCount variable.
[image]

In the Control Flow tab, create control flow connections based on the result of the @RowCount.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to do it:

If file empty means size = 0 you can create a Script Task to do the check:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345166.aspx

```
If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("c:\myfile.txt") Then

  Dim myFileInfo As System.IO.FileInfo
  myFileInfo = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo("c:\myfile.txt")

  If myFileInfo.Length = 0 Then
    Dts.Variables["Status"].Value = 0
  End If
End If
```

Otherwise, if file empty means no rows (flat file) you can use the a Row Count transformation after you reads the file. You can set a variable from the Row Count using the 'VariableName' property in Row Count editor and use it as a status.

Answer (score 1):

Add a simple Script Task with the following code(C#) should do the trick:

```
String FilePath = (string)Dts.Variables["User::FilePath"].Value;

var length = new System.IO.FileInfo(FilePath).Length;

if (length == 0)
    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
else
    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
```

This option will run a lot quicker than the accepted answer as it doesn't need to read the whole file, if you are cycling through a folder of files and some of them are large, in my case ~800mb, the accepted answer would take ages to run, this solution runs in seconds.