# Check for an empty csv file in HTTP location

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, http, ssis, vb.net-2010

I am trying to follow [Determine if file is empty (SSIS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105429/determine-if-file-is-empty-ssis) to see if the file is empty at the HTTP location. I cant download it to begin with as the process is stuck at source and wont let my package finish. All I want to do is to query to source file, if its 0 records, exit the process and send email.

I have the email part working, but I am not sure how to check for the 0 records at source. I am using vb.net as my scripting language. Here's a snippet of what I have so far:

```
Public Sub Main()

        ' Get the unmanaged connection object, from the connection manager called "HTTP Connection Manager"
        Dim nativeObject As Object = Dts.Connections("HTTP_FileName").AcquireConnection(Nothing)

        ' Create a new HTTP client connection
        Dim connection As New HttpClientConnection(nativeObject)



        ' Download the file #1
        ' Save the file from the connection manager to the local path specified
        Dim filename As String = "DestinationPath"
        connection.DownloadFile(filename, True)

        Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
    End Sub
```

**EDIT**

If not 0 records, even a check for a 0kb file at the HTTP location should serve the purpose. It could technically check the filesize and then fail the script so as to raise the appropriate failure message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using Microsoft .Net Framework 4 you can use *System.Net* library to achieve that:

You can Use the Following Code:

```
Imports System.Net

Public Sub Main()

    ' Get the unmanaged connection object, from the connection manager called "HTTP Connection Manager"
    Dim nativeObject As Object = Dts.Connections("HTTP_FileName").AcquireConnection(Nothing)

    ' Create a new HTTP client connection
    Dim connection As New HttpClientConnection(nativeObject)

    Dim webStream As IO.Stream
    Dim req As HttpWebRequest
    Dim res As HttpWebResponse
'Assuming that Dts.Connections("HTTP_FileName").ConnectionString Contains the file URL

    req = WebRequest.Create(Dts.Connections("HTTP_FileName").ConnectionString)

    req.Method = "GET" ' Method of sending HTTP Request(GET/POST)

    res = req.GetResponse() ' Send Request

    webStream = res.GetResponseStream() ' Get Response

    Dim webStreamReader As New IO.StreamReader(webStream)

    If webStreamReader.ReadToEnd.Length = 0 Then
          msgbox("File is Empty")
    Else
          Dim filename As String = "DestinationPath"
          connection.DownloadFile(filename, True)              
    End If

    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
End Sub
```

**Note: the way that @NoAlias provided is working Also**

```
If connection.DownloadData().Length = 0 Then

 'Logic for when there is no data.

End If
```

Comment: Wondering, if the file is 0Kb, can we trigger a task level failure? That would be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Edit of Question:

If it is just a matter of checking the length of the response, you can do this:

```
If connection.DownloadData().Length = 0 Then

     'Logic for when there is no data.

End If
```

You can get the raw string data and validate the file that way:

```
Dim strFileContents = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(connection.DownloadData())

'Example file has header row but no content rows.  Your specific validation will be based 
'on what you're expecting from an empty csv file. 
If strFileContents Is Nothing OrElse  strFileContents.Split(System.Environment.NewLine).Count < 2 Then
     'Empty file.
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for that NoAlias. I tried to retrofit this code into the snipped I provided and it doesn't work. Sorry, not that great with vb.net or C#. Just plain SQL.

Comment: Hmm, you may have to add some references.  See if this helps: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136007.aspx

Comment: I also added a null check on strFileContents, although I don't think that will make a difference.  It's worth a try though.

Comment: The problem is, the file processing is stuck at the upstream source and it is not signaling an end. The file does get downloaded at the end with a 0Kb size, but the script task does not finish. Not sure if this is a known behavior. I will keep this bounty open until we figure out a solution.